# Using Microsoft graph to read all users calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I gave my application the following scopes:

```
SCOPES = [ "Calendars.Read", "User.Read.All" ]
```

I got an access token.  With this token I am able to get the users and I get two users back which is correct.

When I then ask for the calendar of myself (admin):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/stijn@temponia.onmicrosoft.com/calendarview?startDateTime=#{start_date.to_s}&endDateTime=#{end_date.to_s}
```

This also works perfectly.  However when I do this for the other user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/frank@temponia.onmicrosoft.com/calendarview?startDateTime=#{start_date.to_s}&endDateTime=#{end_date.to_s}
```

I get this error message:

```
Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

According to the documentation: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

*Calendars.Read:    Read calendars in all mailboxes:    Allows the app to read events of all calendars without a signed-in user.*

The scope I got back together with the access token was this: "calendars.read user.read.all" so it got accepted.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

We are working to support the scenario you are requesting (Accessing other users' calendars) but the feature hasn't shipped yet.  Stay tuned ...

UPDATE: Please take a look at using client credential flow.  The blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/ explains how to do this for Outlook API endpoint.  But you should be able to follow the instructions for Microsoft Graph as well.

The app will require an admin to consent, and then can access calendar of any user in the organization, as long as their mailbox is in Office 365.

Comment: Hi Venkat, thanks for your reply.  Is there any ETA?  Shouldn't the docs indicate this as, to avoid wasted hours of developers trying to find out what's wrong?

Comment: Agreed and sorry for the trouble this caused.  We will update the docs.  Also, if you are open to using client credential flow OAuth, and have admin consent to the app, there is way to implement your scenario.  Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: absolutely.  My main goal is: admin gives one time permission, and afterwards admin can link my users to AD users (or import AD users) and individual users can import their Outlook into Temponia to transfer them to timesheets.  Without every user needing to give permission.

Comment: @venkat-ayyadevara-msft is my use case possible with your alternative solution?