# Getting 'The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood' in daemon flow office365

Tags: office365, adal, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I had a problem reading all users calendar's which I explained here: [Using Microsoft graph to read all users calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402625/using-microsoft-graph-to-read-all-users-calendars/37403644)

According to the documentation this was available, however it didn't work and the reply was to best use the flow described in the following article (daemon or service app).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

Things I did:
- I registered my web app in Azure portal under active directory.  I set it as a web application (not a native client app).  I set it as multi-tenant and gave application permissions.
- I make a key, edited manifest and uploaded this.

What I'm doing is:

1) get the tenant ID of the user, at this stage the admin user gives permission.

2) as described in the article: I only use the tenantId that I get back, I don't do anything with the access token.

3) I then get a token from https://login.windows.net/TENANT_ID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0  this seems to work as well (after a lot of searching).

4) When I put the access token I got back into https://jwt.io I get a valid result (or so it seems at least), see here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s29/sh/5128795e-e7fd-4b8e-a779-5795cd83a66d/6e67979e1b628b06da60a5dcd5ba99a4

5) Whatever request I make with the access token afterwards I always get:

```
The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.
```

These are the scopes I requested in step 1.

```
SCOPES = [ "openid" "Calendars.Read", "User.Read.All", "offline_access" ]
```

A couple of questions:

- Is it normal that I can throw away the token I get back in step 1 and only use the tenantId.  At this time the user got a message and needed to authorize the site (with the scopes...).  In step 3 the user doesn't get a popup anymore.  If I don't use the token I got then, how can it remember?
- Which endpoints do I need to use?  The post about daemon said **https://outlook.office365.com** but when I'm in active directory of Azure in my app config I see **https://graph.windows.net** if I click the **view endpoints** button.
- In the reply I got on my first question I got: *We are working to support the scenario you are requesting (Accessing other users' calendars) but the feature hasn't shipped yet. Stay tuned ...*  Maybe I need to wait on that, but is there any indication as to when?  Is this a matter of days?  weeks?

Comment: Can edit your question and include some code and/or the requests you are making for each of the steps. Would certainly make it easier to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the blog, it request the id token first. What’s the request for the app-only token you were using? The endpoint https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token is the old one to get the token.

You can refer to the REST below to acquire the app-only token(refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/azure/dn645545.aspx)):

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/o365e3w15.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientID}&client_secret={encodedSecret}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
```

Then we can get the calendars of users we want via the REST below:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com/calendarview?startDateTime=2016-05-01T00:00:00&endDateTime=2016-06-01T08:00:00
authorization: bearer {token}
```

And in the sample above, I used the Microsoft Graph(https://graph.microsoft.com) to request the calendars which is an unified endpoint for multiple APIs from Microsoft cloud services. If you were developing with Exchange REST, you can also use the [single canlenader endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar) https://outlook.office.com replace the resource in the token request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: I used login.windows.net because it is explained like that in the blog.  Just to make sure it's a daemon app I need to create because the other flow didn't allow me to access calendars of other users (see my linked SO question where they advised me to do so).  The flow you explain here is the normal flow but that doesn't work if the admin gave permission and you then query other calendars.

Comment: The flow above is using the client credential flow which is used for the daemon app like you required. Please refer to [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) for the detail about this flow.

Comment: FYI: login.windows.net is indeed the old endpoint for code and token acquisition, but still works (by going direct to login.microsoftonline.com you'll save yourself a hop, but functionally they are the same).  In the Azure Management Portal, request *application* permissions  - the left hand permissions column in your app's config).  Then you'll probably need to get the admin to re-consent to get the permissions set for your daemon app, by sending them to the authorize endpoint (with prompt=consent). Once consented, you can call the token endpoint.  The token should have "roles" claims in it.

Answer (score 0):

To run the application as daemon you need to login using application identity (using the appid and appkey).

Resource:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/"
```

I'm using the ADAL library for dotnet (I'm sure you can find something similar for you), this is my code for login:

```
 public static AuthenticationResult LoginForDaemon(string InTenantName, string InClientId, string InClientAppKey, string InResourceId)
    {
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InTenantName), "InTenantName must be provided");
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InClientId), "InClientId must be provided");
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InClientAppKey), "InClientAppKey must be provided");
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InResourceId), "InResourceId must be provided");

        try
        {
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(InClientId, InClientAppKey);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"https://login.microsoftonline.net/{0}/oauth2/logout", InTenantName));
            return authContext.AcquireToken(InResourceId, clientCredential);
        }
        catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Failed to acquire token silently"))
                return null;
            else
                throw ex;
        }
    }
```