# How to Increase Microsoft Graph API Subscription Limits?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have not been able to find a method of using the graph to subscribe to all users changes, it [looks like it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887080/o365-webhook-subscriptions-for-all-users-calendars).

So I set about subscribing to everyone individually, ideally I would like all updates from calendars, email and contacts eventually, but I started with calendars.

The code works perfectly with just my user, however when I try to subscribe for everyone (around 300 users), I hit a hard a limit, **at seven subscriptions**, as in further requests fail with a generic `Bad Request` status.

In the official docs https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks it says:

> Limitations
>   Certain limits apply and may generate errors when exceeded:
>
> 1) Maximum subscription quotas
>
> - Per App: 50,000 total subscriptions
> - Per Tenant: 35 total subscriptions across all apps
> - Per App and Tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions

It seems that Tenant refers to an actual active directory, so we are limited to 7 per app, or 35 in total.

There is zero chance of splitting users into multi Active Directories of domains, even juggling multiple apps to do the same thing seems strange, these limits make no sense at all to me.

**Is there any way to increase these tiny limits?**

I am subscribing to `users/$email/events` so I post to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhooks.mydomain.com/my/endpoint",
   "resource": "users/$email/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2018-05-12T16:00:00.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "my-super-secret-identifier"
}
```

And it works great, as long as I want <=7 subscriptions. I also subscribed to, the root /users to see if that would give me all changes, which meant I could then only subscribe to 6 individual calendars.

I am using the official PHP library, but presume/hope that doesn't matter.

Comment: I know this isn't the greatest question ever asked on SO, but the graph support page lists Stack Overflow as the official way to get support! https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support  So a little wiggle room for quality, please mods? :)

Comment: 35 per tenant? That makes no sense. Let me try to understand where these numbers came from and figure that part of it out. On the other side with the 300 limit you're hitting, what resource are you subscribing to?

Comment: @JasonJohnston Sorry, poor wording on my side, the hard limit I hit is 7, 300 is the approx number of users in our AD, so that's fine. I have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer, and added example code.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't mean to say you made no sense, but to say the doc'ed limits made no sense :). I checked with the author of that doc and they said that those tiny numbers should only apply to AAD-related endpoints (so /users, for example), not Exchange-related endpoints like /events. A couple of questions: 1) are you doing app-only authentication, or delegated auth? 2) could you post the response headers from a Bad Request response when you hit the limit?

Comment: The weird thing is, it works now! Did something change at Microsoft's side? Because I have no idea what could be different here!

Comment: Nothing changed that I'm aware of :).

Comment: hey @CodeMonkey what does the signature of your "resource" look like for subscribing to everyone? Sounds like i am in the exact same position as you were in. Currently it works perfectly for a single user e.g. "/users/example.email@example.com/messages" but im struggling to figure out what i the signature is for subscribing to everyone.

Comment: hi @pwhc, sorry I never found a way to subscribe to everyone, I have a script that loops through the users, and keeps individual subscriptions up to date, I am currently subscribed to 12 calendars, 223 contact lists, and 223 email endpoints, and everything seems to work fine. If that doesn't fit your use case you might want to look into the deltaToken to get changes since a certain time and check on a schedule

Comment: hey @CodeMonkey - thanks. Ended up doing the same thing; querying all users and setting up individual subscriptions for each user. It seems this is the only way forward - imo its a really clunky solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason said in the comments, the restriction in the question should only have applied to Active Directory Resources, not on the user level, the docs have now been changed:

> **Azure AD Resource Limitations**
>
> Certain limits apply to Azure AD based
>   resources (users, groups) and may generate errors when exceeded:
>
> Maximum subscription quotas:
>
> - Per App: 50,000 total subscriptions
> - Per Tenant: 35 total subscriptions
> - across all apps Per App and Tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions

Whether it was a case of the power of suggestion causing the issue, or some transient bug somewhere I don't know, but the Gods of the Interwebs have smiled on me, and my code works now; even though I didn't change it.

Maybe removing and adding permissions helped in my case? Not sure.

At least the docs are right now.

Comment: If you're having the same issue as the OP and come up with a a satisfying explanation, feel free to leave a better answer! It would also be nice to know I didn't image the entire thing lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an answer (because I can't comment, but this would have helped me to know).

The "AD" in the documentation "Azure AD" means "Active Directory" which seems to be something a little different than *just* the Graph API. In any case, I was able to set up 62 subscriptions, to the same calendar, on the same user, and promptly got 62 notifications after making a change to the calendar. I wanted to test the limits, but I figure 50,000 is a bit much to sit and click the button in the graph API explorer, so I stopped at 62. In any case, it's possible to add more than 7 and more than 35 subscriptions.

The account in question was registered by a company, however apparently not Active directory... Or the documentation is just wrong or being wrongly interpreted. In these cases it's hard to tell sometimes :)

Comment: The line between MS Graph and Azure AD resources is a bit blurry.
Looking at this page: [Working with Azure Active Directory resources in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), it seems that Azure AD resources are related to users and groups information.

Is there an exhaustive list of those resources? (could not find one...)

Also, if there is a limit for Azure AD resources, is there a limit for MS Graph resources?

Answer (score 0):

Now there are more subscriptions allowed. But these are relevant only for Azure-AD managed resources. For example there can be thousands of mailbox subscriptions per App and tenant (I checked personally).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations

```
Maximum subscription quotas:

- Per app (for all tenants combined): 50,000 total subscriptions
- Per tenant (for all applications combined): 1000 total subscriptions across all apps
- Per app and tenant combination: 100 total subscriptions
```