# OneDrive file changed notification subscription cannot be created

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

we are building an Office 365 solution where we need to be notified when there is a change in a user's OneDrive. We are able to create webhook subscription for notifications of file changes using `/beta` Graph API but some user's result in the following error being emitted:

```
Code: ExtensionError 
Message: 
Operation: Create; 
Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden] 
Inner error
```

First, we have thought this was caused due to a bug introduced into our code, which caused the creation of multiple subscriptions for test user accounts. However, after fixing the bug, this issue appeared also for a user account for which we were creating only one subscription.

So far there was only two test users with this issue but plenty of other accounts for which everything works fine. Every tested user has the same settings.

Bellow is the C# code for creating the subscription. We have also tried direct REST API calls with the same results.

```
string clientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string oneDriveResource = resourceUrl + "/drive/root";
GraphServiceClient graphClient;
Subscription subsFromAzure = await graphClient.
Subscriptions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(new Subscription 
    {
        Resource = oneDriveResource, // users/{guid}/drive/root
        ChangeType = "updated",
        NotificationUrl = hooksNotificationUrl,
        ClientState = clientState,
        ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0)
    });
```

Comment: For the users receiving the error, are you able to query the `oneDriveResource` directly (using Graph Explorer)?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur yes querying resources works just fine, only creation of subscriptions is not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can check the permission for test users again, I ever forget to set some permission for very few test accounts.
2. If the permersion is ok. You can try to add a new test account or re-create an existing account to test this again.
3. Adjust your setting to create a new Subscription for all users and check the result.

Due to we don't know your actual configuration, so just some guess. And Microsoft Graph Beta Api is not suggested to be use in the production environment.

Some more [information](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription) may help,note from the "Maximum length of subscription per resource type":
Existing applications and new applications should not exceed the supported value. In the future, any requests to create or renew a subscription beyond the maximum value will fail.

A existing [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275993/how-to-increase-microsoft-graph-api-subscription-limits) may help on this too:
Limitations Certain limits apply and may generate errors when exceeded:

```
Maximum subscription quotas
Per App: 50,000 total subscriptions
Per Tenant: 35 total subscriptions across all apps
Per App and Tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions
```

Comment: We experience this too under MSDN Developer E3 license with 25 users. I dived into settings and found nothing that would be different for those users where it doesn't work. I created new users and for them new subscriptions work fine.

Comment: Moreover when I tried to create subscription on messages for users that cannot have drive subscribed it succeeded. So it seems that only drive cannot be hooked.

Comment: So maybe the latest API haven't fully support all sub-products. Because the Graph API is still in developing.

Comment: Some MS products in MS Graph is still in preview, although most api have been released to production, but the APIs for the product still need to improve.

Comment: I tried more tests on newly created users, that could have drive subscribed. I made 30+ subscriptions manually. All created successfuly. I let them expire. Then I created subscription to the same user using script in a loop. After reaching 16 subscriptions the 17th failed with forbidden error. And now this new account cannot be hooked as all the other old accounts. It looks like as if instead of temporal errror that would prevent me from subscribing more than X times or some throttler I got permanent dead end state.

Comment: Based on your latest test results, maybe between multiple subscription must have the time interval or the subscription for same user have threshold within a certain period of time. I ever face similar issue in the azure mail service but not the subscription